# LinkedIn API Document Posts: Trouble with 'r_member_social' Endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to create document-type posts for an individual using the LinkedIn API. The API documentation suggests that I need to use a specific endpoint called "r_member_social," but I couldn't locate this endpoint anywhere in the documentation or API resources.

As a result, I'm unable to proceed with the process and keep encountering an error whenever I attempt to push documents with a post.

Could you please provide guidance on how to access or utilize the "r_member_social" endpoint for document posts? Alternatively, if there's another approach or endpoint I should be using for document posts, I'd appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

I have referred to the following documents

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/community-management-api-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2024-03#development-tier-access
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2023-08

Both of them mention that it is a closed permission, but my use case is relatively small to apply for the entire API, which might also lead to rejection.